# Add Strings in-between index of ArrayList if not already exists

Tags: java, array

So as the title states, I am trying to add a specific Items to an ArrayList if they not already exist. So here is how the Array starts.

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

I have this items inside the ArrayList

and I'm gonna add some items after the item `d` if it doesn't exist already in a pattern.

```
[a, b, c, d, x, y, z, e, f]
```

I had a successful run of the items I have provided resulting with the output

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
Adding string x to index 3
Adding string y to index 4
Adding string z to index 5
[a, b, c, d, x, y, z, e, f]
String already exists x skipping...
String already exists y skipping...
String already exists z skipping...
[a, b, c, d, x, y, z, e, f]
```

here is the code that I have created to get this result

```
public static void addStringIfNotAlreadyExists(List<String> list, int index, String... strings) {
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (!list.get(index + 1).equals(s)) {
            System.out.println("Adding string " + s + " to index " + index);
            list.add(index + 1, s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("String already exists " + s + " skipping...");
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

It's not the best code I have written but it works.

and here is how I call it for the test.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("e");
    list.add("f");
    System.out.println(list);
    addStringIfNotAlreadyExists(list, 3, "x", "y", "z");
    System.out.println(list);
    addStringIfNotAlreadyExists(list, 3, "x", "y", "z");
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

What I am curious in if this code can fail in certain tests, Or how I can improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

- First of all, as you access the list at `index + 1` without any bounds check, the code will fail if a user attempts to use the method to add elements to the end of the string. You should probably handle that gracefully.
- Changing the input parameter's value `index` is not expressedly forbidden, but it makes my skin crawl. Furthermore, you have to coordinate two values in a loop (`s` and `index`) which makes the code error prone. In this case, I'd go for an index based loop instead `for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)` and use `strings[i]` and `list.get(index + i)`. This way, you have only a single variable changing in the loop.
- If there's nulls in the list, the code will throw an NPE. Preferably use `Objects.equals(x, y)` instead of `x.equals(y)` to stay null-safe.